# Subquery failure: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run the following query on Redshift but I keep getting this error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

The query is as follow:

```
INSERT INTO table_tmp (
 -- straightforward table's schema, fields, datatypes 
 -- the problem is with the SELECT statement that follows
)
SELECT
CHARGEPOINT.Id,
'ABC',
CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus,
NULL,
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.ChargingStationOwner,
CHARGEPOINT.CPOName,
CASE 
    WHEN CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Offline' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Unavailable' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = NULL THEN 'Red'
    WHEN CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Pending' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Unmanaged' THEN 'Amber'
    WHEN CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Online' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Available' THEN 'Green'
END,
NULL,
CAST (CHARGEPOINT.InstallationDate AS timestamp),
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.FirmwareVersion,
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.ManufacturerName,
NULL,
CASE
    WHEN CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Online' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Available' THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END,
NULL,
(SELECT count(CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.Id) FROM x.chargepoint CHARGEPOINT_GROUP GROUP BY CHARGEPOINT.Id),
CHARGEPOINT.IP,
NULL,
CAST (CHARGEPOINT.CreatedAt AS timestamp),
CASE
    WHEN CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Offline' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = 'Unavailable' OR CHARGEPOINT.CurrentStatus = NULL THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END,
NULL,
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.Label,
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.SAPID,
CHARGEPOINT.Serialnumber,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
CHARGEPOINT.IMSI,
CHARGEPOINT.ICCID,
CAST (CHARGEPOINT.LastHeartBeat AS timestamp),
'UPDATE',
current_timestamp,
'ABC',
'',
'',
current_timestamp,
current_timestamp,
TRUE

FROM x.chargept CHARGEPOINT;
```

After some research on previous similar questions, I'm now suspecting that this subquery is the cause of this issue :

```
(SELECT count(CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.Id) FROM x.chargepoint CHARGEPOINT_GROUP GROUP BY CHARGEPOINT.Id)
```

So I've tried using a WITH statement and do this instead:

```
(WITH cte1 AS (
(SELECT count(CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.Id) 
FROM ext_transform_latest_htb.chargepoint CHARGEPOINT_GROUP 
GROUP BY CHARGEPOINT.Id))
SELECT * from cte1),
```

But I got the same error as above.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: `(SELECT count(CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.Id) FROM x.chargepoint CHARGEPOINT_GROUP GROUP BY CHARGEPOINT.Id),` is not a scalar subquery.

Comment: What is `chargepoint`?  `chargept`?  You could simplify the query and provide more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is the problem , because its returning more than 1 row. so how about if you change the subquery to this and give it an alias:

```
... 
, (
        SELECT
            count(CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.Id)
        FROM
            x.chargepoint CHARGEPOINT_GROUP
        WHERE CHARGEPOINT.Id = CHARGEPOINT_GROUP.chargeptid -- < or whatever FK is
) as ChargePointCount
, ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It makes sense. However, now I'm getting another error and I'm not sure how I can locate the field with the problem:
 Invalid operation: Value too long for character type
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Value too long for character type
  code:      8001
  context:   Value too long for type character(40)
  query:     102626
  location:  string.cpp:169
  process:   query1_113_102626 [pid=10408]

Comment: @geosal well seems like you are inserting  more than 40 character in one of your columns , try to find out which column for which value